# Como implementar spinner loanding em AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, spinners

Estou tentando implementar spinner loanding no meu projeto em angularjs, já faz um tempo! o spinner deve rodar sempre que uma requisição for executada.

Que biblioteca uso?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar dessa forma, ele só vai aparecer enquanto `$scope.loading` for `true`.

```js
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {  
  // Show loading spinner.
  $scope.loading = true;
  $http.get('/some/awesome/content')
    .success(function (data) {
      // Do stuff with data.
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // Log error somehow.
    })
    .finally(function () {
      // Hide loading spinner whether our call succeeded or failed.
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">  
  <img id="mySpinner" src="/my/loading/spinner.gif" ng-show="loading" />
</div>
```

Ou para ficar melhor ainda, você pode criar uma diretiva, assim:

```
.directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="loading"><img src="..."/>LOADING...</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
      }
  })
```

Toda vez que você setar `$scope.login = true;` em algum lugar, vai aparecer o loader.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode estar utilizando esse módulo [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) ele é muito fácil de implementar e modificar. Com certeza atende a sua necessidade.

Ele funciona da seguinte forma, toda requisição do serviço `$http` ele irá "capturar" e irá injetar em seu código uma barra de progresso e também no canto inferior direito um loading.

No próprio github do projeto existe uma documentação de como implementar.

Primeiro passo para utiliza-lo é colocar a sua dependência

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

E também não esqueça de colocar seus arquivos no projeto

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='build/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='build/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
```

Feito isso qualquer requisição ele será ativado.

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/83oe6ac2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas maneiras. Caso você queira mostrar o spinner sempre que o Angular fizer uma requisição, implemente uma Interceptor Factory, como na resposta aceita a esta pergunta no SO em Inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838708/implementing-loading-spinner-using-httpinterceptor-and-angularjs-1-1-5

Este interceptor será executado sempre que uma requisição ao serviço $http for feita. A chave é esta linha aqui:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
```

Que injeta o Interceptor no provider.